# Where can I find my SipmleDB domain sizes

Tags: amazon-simpledb

The documentation says that simpledb domain size max is 10GB. However, I can't find anywhere that I can determine what my current domain sizes are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find that info by making a SimpleDB API call to DomainMetadata passing the name of the domain as a parameter.

To determine how close you are to the 10GB size limit, take the sum of the response values:

```
ItemNamesSizeBytes + AttributeNamesSizeBytes + AttributeValuesSizeBytes
```

For reference, here is the [DomainMetadata documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SDB_API_DomainMetadata.html).

Comment: You can also get an idea by looking at the billing, especially if you have only 1 Domain. But you need the API as Mocky says to really do it right. Byte-Hours are reported, which for me meant dividing by 24 hours, then by a million to get MB used: